# How to exit webkitEnterFullscreen mode on android?

Tags: android, jquery, html

On my webpage I am using the following jQuery code to enter the fullscreen mode and play a video:

```
$('#video-play').tap(function(){
    $(this).find('video').get(0).webkitEnterFullScreen();
    $(this).find('video').get(0).play();
});
```

Now, funnily enough, there isn't an exit button on the android full screen web player, so I have absolutely no idea how on earth to stop and exit the video.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming `#video-play` is a container surrounding your video element. You should simply be able to do:

```
$('#video-play').tap(function(){
    $(this).find('video')[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
});
```

If `#video-play` is a play button, without seeing your html, I'd say try this:

```
 $('#video-play').tap(function(){
    $(this).closest('video')[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();
    $(this).closest('video')[0].play();
});
```

Of course providing the html would probably be helpful.

So far I've just found the way to exit a video requires you to hit the back button on the android phone.